# Liferay 7 - Get Dynamic Attributes from DDLRecord in Freemarker

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7

How can I get the dynamic attributes from a DDLRecord inside an Application Display Template (ADT) that has an Asset Publisher type using Freemarker?

As far as I know, I don’t have any other choice that doesn’t involve an Asset Publisher ADT, since I use the filters provided by the Asset Publisher. In case you need context, my Dynamic Data List (DDL) has a date attribute and I need to show the record from the latest date.

Comment: If i am correct, you want to display your list ordered by date right? Would you prefer to display this list in a custom portlet?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible to get dynamic attributes from the asset publisher. However, you can also display your DDL inside a portlet where you can customize your display.

To do this you would need to know the unique id of the DDL (this can be gotten from your liferay admin interface) and the you can elicit the attributes and then order your list as is appropriate for you.

Check out this example

https://github.com/Temire/Getting-DDL-Attribute-Dynamically/blob/master/GetDDLAttributejava

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though, I want to know how to do this in the Asset Publisher, without creating a custom portlet.